# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7_laravel_echo__.Echo is not a constructor in Angular 5

Tags: angular, laravel, websocket, pusher, pusher-js

I am implementing socket.io using laravel pusher in laravel and I have also installed laravel-echo and pusher-js using `npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js` in frontend. But getting error when I am trying to execute following code ,

```
let echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: PUSHER_API_KEY,
  cluster: PUSHER_CLUSTER
});

echo.channel('updateMainGrid')
  .listen('UpdateGridData', (e)=>{
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Please help me to salve this issue.

Comment: Do you do `import Echo from "laravel-echo";` before using Echo?

Comment: yes ,  I have already imported It.

Comment: Actually what I have found is when I hover on import { Echo } from 'laravel-echo'  then warning comes in popup is `Could not find a declaration file for module 'laravel-echo'. /node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/laravel-echo` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'laravel-echo';`ts(7016)`.

Comment: Is the import and declaration is in same scope?, because if it is not, you need to set it to `window.` so it can be accessed globally.

Comment: yes boss , it's in same scope 

Comment: @HitendraPatil did you ever find a solution to this?